# ng-click not working on replaced element

Tags: angularjs

Here I'm trying to replace a button with a place-holder div and the button will goes to upper panel. And when the button returns back to the lower panel the ng-click works no more. 
I need the buttons work like before it was there.
I cannot use $compile, because it appends child to lower panel, but I only need to replace.  Here is my     [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

```
    // Code goes here

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('demo', [
        // Angular modules
        //'dndLists'
    ]);
    angular
        .module('demo')
        .controller('buttonController', buttonController);

    buttonController.$inject = ['$scope','$compile','$document'];

    function buttonController($scope,$compile,$document) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'buttonController';
        var btns=[
            {name:'btn-1',class:'active'},
            {name:'btn-2',class:'active'},
            {name:'btn-3',class:'active'},
            {name:'btn-4',class:'active'}
        ];
        $scope.answerButtons = [];
        $scope.buttons = btns;

        $scope.pushArray = function (item,$event) {
            //inset new element to upper panel
            $scope.answerButtons.push(item);
            //replace lower element with a laceholder
            var oldElem=angular.element($event.target);
            var parentNode=oldElem[0].parentNode;
            var newNode=document.createElement('div');
            newNode.className='placeholder';
            newNode.id=item.name;
            parentNode.replaceChild(newNode,oldElem[0]);
        };

        $scope.removeArray = function (item) {
            //remove element from upper panel
            var index = $scope.answerButtons.indexOf(item);
            $scope.answerButtons.splice(index, 1);
            //create new element for replacing into lower panel
            var newNode=document.createElement('div');
            newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name));
            newNode.className='btn btn-primary active';
            var att=document.createAttribute("ng-repeat");
            att.value="item in buttons";
            newNode.setAttributeNode(att);
            att=document.createAttribute("ng-click");
            att.value="pushArray(item,$event)";
            newNode.setAttributeNode(att);

            //Replace previous elemnt in place of place holder
            var oldElem=document.getElementById(item.name);
            var parentNode=oldElem.parentNode;
            parentNode.replaceChild(newNode,oldElem);
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: you need to compile element with the controller scope

Comment: plunker link is not working

Comment: $compile(parentNode.contents())($scope); try this in last of remove method

Comment: While you can probably get this to work, the bottom line is: don't attempt to manipulate the DOM from inside an angular controller. Use angular's directives to create the DOM then you won't have this sort of problem, and your code will be a lot shorter as well.

Comment: This approach to using angular is completely wrong. Update your data model ... not the DOM. Let angular manage the DOM from the data model. There should ***never*** be any DOM manipulation code in controller

Comment: This is what happens when I use $compile
https://plnkr.co/edit/poKwG4z1CiLqvIvKN8eH?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Never try to manipulate the DOM from your angular controller. Manipulate your data model instead and simply make sure the template generates the correct html. Here's what I think you are trying to do:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('demo', [
        // Angular modules
        //'dndLists'
    ]);
    angular
        .module('demo')
        .controller('buttonController', buttonController);

    buttonController.$inject = ['$scope','$compile','$document'];

    function buttonController($scope,$compile,$document) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'buttonController';
        var btns=[
            {name:'btn-1',class:'active'},
            {name:'btn-2',class:'active'},
            {name:'btn-3',class:'active'},
            {name:'btn-4',class:'active'}
        ];
        $scope.answerButtons = [];
        $scope.buttons = btns;

        $scope.pushArray = function (item) {
            //inset new element to upper panel
            $scope.answerButtons.push(item);
            item.placeholder = true;
        };

        $scope.removeArray = function (item, index) {
            //remove element from upper panel
            $scope.answerButtons.splice(index, 1);
            item.placeholder = false;
        };
    }
})();
```

and the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="demo">
      <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
      <div ng-controller="buttonController">
        <div class="panel panel-default fixed-sized">
          <div class="btn btn-primary {{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in answerButtons" ng-click="removeArray(item,$index)">{{item.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-danger fixed-sized">
          <div class="btn btn-primary {{item.class}}"
            ng-repeat-start="item in buttons"
            ng-if="!item.placeholder"
             ng-click="pushArray(item,$index)">{{item.name}}</div>
          <div class="placeholder"
            ng-if="item.placeholder" ng-repeat-end></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all that placeholder stuff, use `ng-class` to disable the button.

```
      <div class="btn btn-primary {{item.class}}"
                ng-repeat="item in buttons"
                ng-click="pushArray(item,$event)"
                ng-class="{disabled: item.srcDisable}">
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
```

Replace all that DOM manipulation with simple code.

```
    $scope.pushArray = function (item,$event) {
        if (item.srcDisable) return;
        item.srcDisable = true; 
        //inset new element to upper panel
        $scope.answerButtons.push(item);
    };

    $scope.removeArray = function (item) {
        item.srcDisable = false;
        //remove element from upper panel
        var index = $scope.answerButtons.indexOf(item);
        $scope.answerButtons.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

CSS

```
    .active{
        background-color:blue !important;
        color:white;
    }
    .disabled {
        background-color:dimgrey !important;
        color:dimgrey;
    }
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/vBBDU4tNQB7KaBAnfsw9?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot @georgeawg